# How can I get UWSGI to log Flask log messages at the correct level?

Tags: flask, uwsgi, systemd-journald

I have a uwsgi service running under systemd. It appears to be logging everything it received from its hosted Flask application as `INFO` level, rather than whatever level it was supposed to be logged under.

In my Python code, I have a Flask application called `app`. I call:

`app.logger.error('TESTING LOGGING')`

When I check my logs using `journalctl -u uwsgi -p err`, I don't see the message I logged. When I use `journalctl -u uwsgi -p info`, I do.

I'm not using the *systemd_logger* plugin for uwsgi, but it doesn't look like it would fix this problem, because it also always logs at `INFO` level: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/3149df02ed443131c54ea6afb29fcbb0ed4d1139/plugins/systemd_logger/systemd_logger.c#L13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWSGI won't log these messages to the right level, but I was able to do it directly from within Flask, by using the Python systemd package.

```
import logging
from systemd import journal

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
journaldHandler = journal.JournalHandler()
logger.addHandler(journaldHandler)

logger.error('TESTING LOGGING')
```

https://pypi.org/project/systemd/